# How to see exception message in Google Chrome while paused?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, debug

I'm using Google Chrome for debugging JavaScript. I opened up the JavaScript Console and the "Pause on Exception" feature is enabled. Now whenever I run JavaScript that has an exception in it, it pauses on the line with the exception. However, I can't find where it says what the exception is. I have to press continue script execution for the exception message to be displayed in the JavaScript console.

With every other debugger I have used, whenever the debugger stops on a line, it tells you what was wrong with the line (i.e. the error message is shown). It seems odd that you have to press "run" before you see the error message.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this the only way to see the error messages?

Comment: Rather oddly, I don't think there is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting many other resources, I've come to the conclusion that there isn't a way to change this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the call stack--'raise exception'--on the right-hand side of the script editor?

Answer (score 2):

On the right side of the editor, under the section labeled "Scope Variables", an item should appear under the Local node named "<exception>", which represents the thrown exception object.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Chrome (I'm seeing it in 38) show the exception message underneath the stack trace:

[image: stack trace]